# Identify a comic from the 80s in Métal Hurlant

Tags: story-identification, comics

Featuring a very large dumb and strong "Frankenstein's monster/cyborg" with small sunglasses reminiscent or old fashioned tanning bed glasses or swim goggles on a scarred face.
He was a sidekick of a young clever girl/woman with a lot of weapons.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is [RanXerox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RanXerox) by Stefano Tamburini and Tanino Liberatore. RanXerox is an android built from photocopier spare parts (hence the name, and hence a lawsuit with Xerox that lead to a renaming of the character) who is protector and lover of the underage Lubna. Rather distasteful by todays standards, visually somewhat impressive, and definitely NSFW.

[image: Ranxerox]

(Wikipedia claims fair use for use of the image, so do I).

Comment: Thanks! I cannot remember details but I had a cool badge with his face and lost it. (And I was listening to Frank Zappa, whose "The Man from Utopia now suddenly gets another dimension for me)
The comics I was reading in the early '80s were quite alternative - like The Fabulous Furry Freak Brothers and MAD magazine. When I was in France, I was reading Métal Hurlant and L'echo des savanes which also contained a lot of Gilbert Shelton and was very NSFW.

Comment: This is a comic about a robot who has graphic sex with a 12 year old and smashes peoples skulls to pulp in hyperrealistic detail. That is yet another level of NSFW  than Fritz the Cat, and that is saying something.

Comment: Well, it is also a work of art with some pop-cultural significance (Zappa record covers etc). The past does not improve if you pretend it's not there, so let's just warn people and otherwise let the question stand.